# Job crashes with OOM when I submit as a que (PBS/Torque) but not when I run simply run the command in terminal

Tags: bash, pbs, torque

Here's the job script I use,

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -q batch
#PBS -N simulation
#PBS -j n
#PBS -o /dev/null
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1,pmem=3400mb
#PBS -l ncpus=1,mem=3400mb

cd ${PBS_O_WORKDIR} && \

./executable
```

I get this error:

```
Operating system error: Cannot allocate memory
Allocation would exceed memory limit
```

I've tried increasing the ppn and ncpus and mem such that it matches requirement of my program (~6GB). Doesn't help either.

This doesn't happen when I run the command in terminal. It works just fine.

Comment: check the tracejob output with `tracejob {your_job_id}`. Try increasing `mem` and `pmem` above 6GB and see what data would `tracejob` report. Then update your post with additional details.

Comment: What version of Torque are you using that allows you to supply both nodes and ncpus values for your resource request?

Answer (score 0):

Try run the program with all memory in the system allocated to the job.
Then at the very end execute `qstat -f $PBS_JOBID| grep resources` to see what Torque thinks about used resources.

```
resources_used.cput = 00:00:00
resources_used.energy_used = 0
resources_used.mem = 94724kb
resources_used.vmem = 1564024kb
resources_used.walltime = 00:03:25
```